# Simplest Group By / Sum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

What's the simplest way to sum a two column pandas dataframe but keep it as a dataframe?

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
         sum1  sum2
0    8153.035  1132
1   12730.100  1559
2   10845.360  1268
3    6694.075   900
4    3740.105   608
5    3247.225   232
6    4579.725   646
7    9225.150  1184
8   12371.885  2346
9   11670.025  1805
10   1088.000   183
11     14.460     3
12   9027.055  1282
13  18880.855  2107
```

What's the simplest and most efficient way to sum it to a dataframe that looks like:

```
        sum1   sum2
0  109019.83  15023
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.sum().to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
         sum1     sum2
0  112267.055  15255.0
```

You could just do `df.sum()` to get the series

```
sum1    112267.055
sum2     15255.000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking. Can just do

```
df = df.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Indeed. `axis=0` is the default, so you can leave it out.

Comment: The above produces a Series.  `s = pd.DataFrame(df.sum()).transpose()` produce what is specified in your question.

Comment: @gongzhitaao And that's exactly what I do in my answer.